# Flutter - Google Maps - Remove POI Layer

Tags: google-maps, flutter

It's well documented on the Google Maps web version, but I can't find the same feature in the Flutter GM module.
I need to hide the points of interests from the map (shops, bus stops...)
Is there any official / unofficial way to do it, or another module that would handle it ?

Comment: what plugin / lib do you use for the maps?

Comment: google_maps_flutter

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to remove POI, the only work around is to use `mapType: MapType.terrain`

Comment: What about modifying the native code of the plugin. Is this even possible ?

Comment: You can always fork the packages repo and make modifications to the google_maps_flutter package. The repo can be found here: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter

Comment: @brandon-irl I ended up doing that and it worked.

Comment: @brandon-irl Thanks. how to update package after fork?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you can!

okay first as you know, GoogleMaps accepts theming, you can get dark or any customized map you like through this link (https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com) you can get json to insert in your app.

you can also follow this guide (https://medium.com/@matthiasschuyten/google-maps-styling-in-flutter-5c4101806e83).

okay to get back to your question, while theming you can turn on/off features and from those POI.

so you can add this to your json and POI will disappear

```
{
  "featureType": "poi",
  "stylers": [
    { "visibility": "off" }
  ]
}
```

if you want only default googleMaps with only POI removed you can use this json

```
 [
    {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "stylers": [
        { "visibility": "off" }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

another example: this is my full settings. theming and at the end i disabled POI

```
[
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ebe3cd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#523735"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f1e6"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#c9b2a6"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dcd2be"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ae9e90"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.natural",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dfd2ae"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dfd2ae"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#93817c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#a5b076"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#447530"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f1e6"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#fdfcf8"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f8c967"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e9bc62"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e98d58"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#db8555"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#806b63"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dfd2ae"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#8f7d77"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ebe3cd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.station",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dfd2ae"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#b9d3c2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#92998d"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Thor Mitchell, (Former Product Mgr, Google Maps API) said that here : (https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-remove-POI-from-the-Google-Maps-API)

that's all ^^

---

**Edit (14 Oct 19) :
so to be more clear. here is the steps, all of it.**

1- create mapStyle.txt in assets folder ex:

[image: MapStyle.txt]

and it contains just this text

```
[{
     "featureType": "poi",
     "stylers": [
       {
         "visibility": "off"
       }
     ]
   }]
```

2- add it to pubspec.yaml assets ex:

```
  assets:
    - assets/map_style.txt
```

3- in your map screen do the following

```
class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  String _mapStyle;
  GoogleMapController _mapController;

  initState() {
    super.initState();
    rootBundle.loadString('assets/map_style.txt').then((string) {
      _mapStyle = string;
    });
  }

//...

  _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    if (mounted)
      setState(() {
        _mapController = controller;
        controller.setMapStyle(_mapStyle);
      });
  }

//...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        zoom: 15,
        target: LatLng(
          _currentPosition?.latitude,
          _currentPosition?.longitude,
        ),
      ),
      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
      polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(_polyLines.values),
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      compassEnabled: true,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the question was about Flutter. This looks like a solution for JS ?

Comment: Updated Answer with more details, i hope it's clear now.

Comment: This works, though gestures don't seem as smooth afterwards.

Comment: [@Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463841/scott) , i don't think it's a problem with json configs itself, you might want to open issue for flutter team at [Flutter Github Repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues).

Comment: This is awesome. Even provided the nice website.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`setMapStyle` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMapController/setMapStyle.html) on your `GoogleMapController`:

```
yourMapController.setMapStyle('[{"featureType": "poi","stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]}]');
```

To generate such strings for customizing the map style, you can use [this](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) website.

Answer (score 1):

> Go to https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com

[image]

> **Here you can adjust the degree of labels visibility**

[image]

**Then click on finish and copy the JSON file to your app**

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

```
  void _setMapStyle() async {
String style = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
    .loadString('assets/map_style.json');
_googleMapController!.setMapStyle(style);
```

}

```
onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController googleMapController) {

               _googleMapController = googleMapController;
               _setMapStyle();

              },
```